# Can't get status of sms from Twilio

Tags: python, sms, response, twilio, status

I had some issue when works with Twilio API. I tried to get sms status as is delivered, queue, failed or another, but I couldn't find this method at Rest API.

I use Python and Django.

```
def send_sms(self, msg):
    ACCOUNT_SID = self.profile.twilio_sid
    AUTH_TOKEN = self.profile.twilio_auth_token
    client_phone_number = self.profile.phone_number
    twilio_phone_number = "+1"+str(self.profile.twilio_number)
    client = TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN)
    message = client.messages.create(
        body=msg,
        to=client_phone_number,
        from_=twilio_phone_number,
    )
    sid = message.sid
```

So how can I get sms status with sid what i have? Without response processing if it is possible

I found answer. All what I need is added to my code

```
body  = client.messages.get(sid)
status =body.status
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer. All what I need is added to my code

```
body  = client.messages.get(sid)
status = body.status
```

Answer (score 1):

Twilio evangelist here.

To get an individual instance resource, use resources.ListResource.get(). Provide the sid of the resource you’d like to get.

```
msg  = client.messages.get(sid)
print msg.to
```

You could also provide a status callback URL when you sent the message to have Twilio notify you via a webhook request when the message status changes:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages#post-parameters-optional

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, you really help me to get context from response.

Answer (score 1):

```
Message message = twilio.GetMessage(messageSid);
```